# IP network routing: restrict traffic on an interface

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, routing

My PC has wired and wireless Ethernet.
The wired port connects to a private network with no Internet access.
the wireless port connects to a domain network with Internet access.

The problem is that the wired port has a lower metric so Windows tries to route traffic intended for the Internet through that port. How can I ensure that ONLY traffic for the private network goes through the wired interface, and everything else through wireless?

Answer (score 1):

Set a route.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx

Enter command line and write a route, probably somewhat like this:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.17
```

where the first ip is your private network and the last ip is the ip of your network card (can be looked up with `ipconfig`)

If you want a route that survives a reboot you need to add the `-p` option. If you want to remove the route again you use

```
route delete 192.168.1.0
```

if you want to look at all routes and their priorities, use

```
route print
```

You can route all traffic through `10.43.11.15` like this:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.43.11.15
```

And then you can use a metric argument to give tor route for local addresses higher priority (add a number at the end of the command line, see documentation `route /?`)

Comment: Routing traffic to the private network is not a problem... it's routing all other traffic. How would this help?

Comment: Make the wireless card the default route for everything else. Then this makes sure you still route your private network through the wired card.